# How to make a server API tell a client API that an update is available

Tags: java, rest, web-services, webservice-client

I have rest client API accessing data through `/read` endpoint from my server. However, I have an `internal batch service` that calls my server's `/write` endpoint which updates the data. So from time to time the data from the server gets updated. How will I tell the client that the data is updated and ask it to call the `/read` endpoint again to get the latest data?

Below is a highlevel diagram on the scenario.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try learning webhooks? Basically, the client will "subscribe" to your webhook, or to make it easier, the client will provide an endpoint to the server. Whenever there's an update, your server just sends a request to the client. The client *should simply call a service* that, whenever it receives a request from the webhook, fetches `read`.

It basically goes like this

- Client subscribes to server
- The client gives the server an endpoint `/updateAvailable`
- When there's an update, the server sends a request to client's endpoint `/updateAvailable`
- '/updateAvailable' invokes a service that calls on '/read'

The '/updateAvailable' endpoint could invoke a service that updates content. Let's say the request sent has a parameter

```
{
   "updateFound":true
}
```

So whenever the client's '/updateAvailable' is called and receives a request, you do something like this (pseudo code)

```
if (updateBody.updateFound.message=true)
then call read()
```

**Edit**

By creating an endpoint for client, you can also do automatic updates. So client has an `/updateAvailable` endpoint. The server sends the update to the `/updateAvailable` endpoint, which from the client side invokes whatever service is used for `/read`

Comment: Hi Rigo, Thanks for the suggestion. Any samples/ links would be much appreciated. I would be using springboot

Comment: You could simply do as I say. Just have the client create an endpoint `/updateAvailable`. Then whenever server finds an update, the server sends a request to `/udpateAvailable` saying there's an update available.

Comment: Hi Rigo, Thanks for your suggestions again, I do understand the idea behind, however you mean to say that server can call client using webhooks ? or using httpservlet dispatcher call from server to client

Comment: Yes i own the client as welll

Comment: Nevermind webhooks if you haven't learned it yet. You can learn it after trying to solve this problem. To solve this problem, just give a new endpoint to the client `/updateAvailable`. Now whenever there's an update, the server sends a request to the client's endpoint `/updateAvailable` telling it that there is an update. So now the client knows that there's an update.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions for your question:

1. Using timer on restful client to request to restful server in every N seconds/minutes... However, it's really bad idea because it has to request to server many times even though there's no updated data.
2. Using third party publish-subscribe-based messaging protocol solutions to implement push notification feature whenever there is new data updated. These solutions are:  Google FCM,MQTT,AMQP